# How to run celery workers by superuser?

Tags: python, linux, celery

When I run celery workers with sudo, i get the following error:

```
Running a worker with superuser privileges when the
worker accepts messages serialized with pickle is a very bad idea!

If you really want to continue then you have to set the C_FORCE_ROOT
environment variable (but please think about this before you do).

User information: uid=0 euid=0 gid=0 egid=0
```

also my **C_FORCE_ROOT** environment variable is **true**:

```
echo $C_FORCE_ROOT
true
```

More information:
Python --> 2.7.6
celery --> 3.1.23 (Cipater)
OS     --> Linux(Ubuntu 14.04)

How should I run celery with sudo? I know it's not secure but for some reasons I really need to do it!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK I found the solution!
In celery 3.1 and above, workers with pickle serialization will crash as mentioned in [documentation](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/whatsnew-3.1.html):

> Worker will now crash if running as the root user with pickle enabled.

So to use sudo, you need to disable pickle serialization in celery configs.I did it by using json:

```
app.conf.update(
     CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['json'],
     CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json',
     CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json',
)
```

and then if you run using sudo, it will work!